# Pyhton: ¿Cómo puedo realizar una especie de Full Outer Join en un DataFrame en Python con tipo de datos: cadena de caracteres?

Tags: python, string, join

Saludos para todos y todas. Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo un datafrase con 5 columnas las cuales todas son de tipo cadenas de texto. Necesito crear una nueva columna con las cadenas diferentes, es decir, hacer una especie de Full Outer Join pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo con este tipo de datos, es decir, con datos de tipo numérico es fácil, pero no se me ocurre la forma de hacerlo con caracteres.

**Columna 1:** "Pedro Perez tiene gripa 
**Columna 2:** "Pedro Perez tiene gripa y toz"
**Columna 3:** "Pedro Perez debe ir al médico" 
**Columna 4:** Pedro Perez
**Columna 5:** Pedro
**Columna esperada:** Pedro Perez tiene gripa y toz de ir al médico

Cualquier ayuda posible que me puedan brindar de manera tal que pueda continuar con esta dificultad es bien recibida.

Gracias de antemano comunidad.

Comment: No comprendo, quieres unir por la primera palabra? Un "full outer join" en `pandas` es un `merge`, y se usa en dos dataframes distintos. Entiendo que como son varias columnas en un solo dataframe, no es realmente lo que buscas, correcto?

Comment: Adicionalmente serviría de mucho que muestres lo que has podido avanzar y chequees cómo preguntar correctamente aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No es un problema de pandas. El problema es tomar 5 textos y producir uno que los incluya a todos.

Comment: @CandidMoe específicamente el OP dice: *hacer una especie de Full Outer Join*.De todos modos, a la pregunta le hacen falta aclaraciones, por lo tanto no es respondible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es de Pandas, sino de juntar los cinco textos en uno solo. Una vez formado el texto, agregarlo al dataframe es trivial.

El método para juntar y producir algo razonablemente coherente es el siguiente:

Las frases se desglosan en palabras. Cada frase es una lista de palabras y el conjunto de frases forma una matriz irregular. Formalmente, tenemos una lista de listas.

Se analiza la primera columna y se selecciona la palabra más frequente. Esa palabra es ahora parte de la salida. A continuación se arma una submatriz con todas las líneas que contiene la palabra más frecuente en la primera columna, y se aplica recursivamente el procedimiento hasta dejar vacia la matriz.

El código es:

```
def mas_frecuente(lista):
    """ Retorna la palabra más frecuente en la lista
    
        @param lista: lista de palabras.
        @return string, la palabra más frecuente.
    """
    ord = [[lista.count(word), word] for word in lista]
    return max(ord)[1]
    
def juntar(lista):
    """ Junta una lista de frases.
    
    @param lista: Una lista de frases.
    @return string, todas las frases resumidas en una sola.
    """
    matriz = [frase.split() for frase in lista]
    salida = procesar(matriz)
    return " ".join(salida)


def procesar(matriz):
    """ Procesa una matriz de frases.

    @matriz: Una lista de frases. Cada fila contiene una frase
             expresada como una lista de palabras.
    @return: Una lista de palabras que reune todas las frases.
    """
    salida = []

    while True:
        #
        # Seleccionar primer palabra en primera columna.
        #
        columna = [row[0] for row in matriz if len(row)]
        if len(columna) == 0:
            break
        #
        # Buscar palabra más comùn y agregarla a la frase de salida.
        #
        salida.append(mas_frecuente(columna))
        #
        #   Eliminar la palabra de la primera columna
        #   Armar una submatriz con aquellas filas que
        #   contengan la palabra mas frecuente, y aplicar
        #   el proceso recursivamente.
        #
        nueva = []
        for index in range(len(matriz)):
            row = matriz[index]
            largo = len(row)
            if largo and row[0] == salida[-1]:
                row.pop(0)
                if largo > 1:
                    nueva.append(row)
                    matriz[index] = []
        salida.extend(procesar(nueva))

    #
    # Terminar la frase de salida con todos los textos restantes.
    #         
    salida.extend([row for row in matriz if len(row)])
    return salida
```

**Comprobación**

Hicimos este programa de prueba

```
lista1 = ["Pedro Perez tiene gripe", 
    "Pedro Perez tiene gripe y toz",
    "Pedro Perez debe ir al mèdico",
    "Pedro Perez",
    "Pedro"
    ]

lista2 = ["María",
          "María lleva el cubo al establo",
          "María lleva la vaca al establo",
          "María quiere ordeñar",
          "María quiere desayunar"
        ]

lista3 = ["Juana",
          "María",
          "Juana y María toman té",
          "van juntas al colegio",
          "María es más alta"
        ]

for test in [lista1, lista2, lista3]:
    print(juntar(test))
```

que arroja estos resultados:

```
candid@dell ~ $ python3 juntar.py
Pedro Perez tiene gripe y toz debe ir al mèdico
María quiere ordeñar desayunar lleva la vaca al establo el cubo al establo
María es más alta Juana y María toman té van juntas al colegio
```

Los resultados son un poco surrealistas. Tal vez el código pueda servir para crear poesía dadaista.